# How to call javascript function inside asp hyperlink that includes an Eval

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, hyperlink, popup

Good afternoon, I have a gridview with an asp:hyperlink TemplateField. On click I want to trigger a popup window. My js looks like this.

```
<script>
    function popups(url) {
        newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=300,width=735');
        if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

The non popup version of the code is below.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="PriceListItemID" ID="lnkQty" runat="server" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../PricingTool/PriceListQuantity.aspx?PriceListItemID={0}" Text='<%# Bind("NumQty") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "../PricingTool/PriceListQuantity.aspx?PriceListItemID=" + Eval("PriceListItemID") %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

I have made a few attempts that result in the error "The server tag is not well formed." including the broken code below.

```
<asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="PriceListItemID" ID="lnkQty" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NumQty") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "Javascript:popups.show('../PricingTool/PriceListQuantity.aspx?PriceListItemID=" + Eval("PriceListItemID").ToString() + "')" %>' />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your **JavaScript** function/code inside the `OnClick` attribute:

```
<asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" OnClick="popups();" />
```

Comment: That is what I attempted in the beginning. But I am passing the url  to the function and it does not seem to work.

    <asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFields="PriceListItemID" ID="lnkQty" runat="server" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="../PricingTool/PriceListQuantity.aspx?PriceListItemID={0}" Text='<%# Bind("NumQty") %>' OnClick="popups(<%# "../PricingTool/PriceListQuantity.aspx?PriceListItemID=" + Eval("PriceListItemID") %>);" />

Comment: I think that the problem is in the quotes, repalce onClick for single quotes: OnClick='popups(<%# "../PricingTool/PriceListQuantity.aspx?PriceListItemID=" + Eval("PriceListItemID") %>);'

Comment: I attempted to use single quotes and did not get an error. But when I hover over the number being printed, nothing happens. When I click, the js is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the method like this in the OnClick:

```
<asp:HyperLink Target="_blank" OnClick="Javascript:popups(url);" />
```

Comment: So this: OnClick='Javascript:popups(<%# "../PricingTool/PriceListQuantity.aspx?PriceListItemID=" + Eval("PriceListItemID") %>);' results in the link doing nothing. and double quotes surrounding the event, (OnClick="blah") breaks.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure that concatenating the URL string inside of the passed parameter would work. Another suggestion is to change OnClick to OnClientClick. If the parameter is still giving you an issue, you can think about doing that logic in a javascript variable, and then passing that variable when you call the method.